# How to use data serialized from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a problem.
I have an ajax call that have two data to send, one is a form serialized the other is a other variable, i don't know how to use the variables into the first data of ajax call ( the form serialized ) into PHP, how can i do this?

JS:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: "/update",
        type: "post",
        data:
            {
                form: $("#formTeamLeaderProduzione").serialize(),
                type: "TeamLeaderProduzione"
            },

        success: function (data)
        {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data))
        },

        error: function (msg)
        {
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }

    });
```

PHP:

```
Route::post('/update', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{

     $value = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('form');

     return response()->json($request->form->inputModificaNomeTeamLeaderProduzione1,200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my anwser

```
Route::post('/update', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{

    parse_str($request->input('form'), $form);

    return response()->json($form['inputModificaNomeTeamLeaderProduzione1'],200);
});
```